# new Line not recognized in shell script on Linux

Tags: java, linux, shell

I wrote a shell script on the Linux Ubuntu server.
And I want to run a shell script on Java.

Running the shell script inside the Linux server changes the way I wrote it, but not through Java.

I'll show you Java code, shell script file, and capture screen.

**Java**

```
public class ShellScriptApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String start = "start";
        String stop = "stop";
        String name = "";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("start or stop? : ");
        String s = sc.nextLine();

        if(s.equals(start)) {
            System.out.print("시작하실 프로그램을 입력해주세요 [admin / ap / json / fixed] : ");
            name = sc.nextLine();
            openShell(start, name);
        } else if (s.equals(stop)) {
            System.out.print("종료하실 프로그램을 입력해주세요 [admin / ap / json / fixed] : ");
            name = sc.nextLine();
            openShell(stop, name);
        } else {
            System.out.println("wrong");
        }

    }

    public static String openShell(String status, String name)  {
        String result = "";

        String dir = "/data/GSLinkIN/app";

        String cdExec = "cd " + dir + " && ./"+ name + "-" + status + ".sh";

        String [] command = {"/bin/sh","-c", cdExec};
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.command(command);

        try {
            // Run script
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            // Read output
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line);
            }
            if(output.toString().equals("")) {
                result = "success";
            }else {
                result = output.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = "fail";
        }
        System.out.println(result);

        return result;
    }

}
```

**stop.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

APP_NAME=linkin-admin-www-2.0.war
APP_PID=$(ps -ef | grep $APP_NAME | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')

echo "$APP_NAME (PID:$APP_PID)"
kill -9 $APP_PID
echo "$APP_NAME stopped"
```

**When running a shell script using Java**
[image: When running a shell script using Java]

**When running directly on a Linux server**

[image: When running directly on a Linux server]

Even if I run a shell script over Java, I want to print the PID and then get a new line.

Comment: From the screenshot, we see that the script is executed in both cases, so at least invoking it works fine, so the possible problems are most likely inside the script. It is strange that the first `echo` does not show in the output, where the parent process is your Java program. This makes me wonder whether you REALLY execute the very same script in both cases. For verifying this (and possibly see, what's going wrong), I suggest that you replace `-c` by `-xc` when invoking the script, and analyze the output you get.

Comment: it still works the same I so proceeded with armali's reply but thanks for commenting!! @user1934428

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> new Line not recognized

The newline is well recognized, it's just that [`readLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--)

> Returns:
>
> A String containing the contents of the line, not including
>             any line-termination characters…

so you have to re-insert them if you want them in the result.
While you're at it, I suggest to shorten

```
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line);
            }
            if(output.toString().equals("")) {
                result = "success";
            }else {
                result = output.toString();
            }
```

to

```
            result = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            if (result.equals("")) result = "success";
```